# Removing Space from Stored Table row with Procedure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I was looking for a stored procedure for SQL server 2005 to remove leading, trailing and other spaces of records stored in the table.

Basically, I needed to bulk insert data into my Database, and the table that I am working on contains blank spaces in various records. Take an instance of Pincode/Zip code, that cannot have spaces between them but the data I have inserted had spaces in most of the pincodes like "**110 001**", however it should be "**110001**". In other columns the data is in form of " **data** " where it should be "**data**"

I have already inserted the data but, I need to format it now, so as to arrange it in proper form.

Comment: Are you looking for a generic version or simply using REPLACE and UPDATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) . Try

`REPLACE(Pincode, ' ', '')`

**UPDATE:**

If you need to update data in a table

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Pincode = REPLACE(Pincode, ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use UPDATE with Replace function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx